# Difficulty setting up a dropdown menu filter for Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping, geojson

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so apologies in advance for anything I'm not able to express correctly.

I'm making an interactive map showing info on several NGOs in Spain. So far, I've managed to set the markers (through a GEOJson file that I converted to .js), cluster them and have the pop-up appear when clicking on each of them. Now I need to be able to filter which markers appear on the map depending on one of the properties of each marker (in this case, I called it "tematica").

I tried to follow the example from this link https://mappinggis.com/2019/11/filtrando-datos-geograficos-en-formato-geojson-con-leaflet/ (sorry it's in Spanish, but the code is pretty self-explanatory), but they don't show how their geojson .js file is organized. When I try to adapt their code to my project, I can't seem to make it work. Cand anybody tell me what I have wrong?

Here's an example of the Geojson:

`{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"coder_ID": "CHB","name": "Entorno Escorial","tematica": "Medio Ambiente","bio": "Organización medioambiental de El Escorial y de San Lorenzo de El Escorial","redes": "","website": "","CCAA": "Madrid","MAmbiente": true,"Educacion": false,"JSocial": false,"CClima": false,"TransEnerg": false,"AgroEco": false,"SobAlim": false,"EcoFem": false,"Invest": "false"},"geometry": {"coordinates": [-4.147899127581563,40.59572974584587],"type": "Point"}}`

And here is my JavaScript:

```
    const map = L.map('map').setView([40.382439468640214, -3.745878127504685], 6);

    const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    const geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#37b18c",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

    const markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    var layer = L.geoJson (data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('<h1>'+feature.properties.name+'</h1><p>Tematica: '+feature.properties.tematica+'</p><p>'+feature.properties.bio+'</p>');
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            }
            });
            markers.addLayer(layer);
            map.addLayer(markers);

    /*L.geoJSON(data, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
            return markers.addLayer (L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions))
        }
    }).addTo(map);*/

    map.addLayer(markers);

    function tematicaSelect() {
        var miSelect = document.getElementById("ambito").value;
            
        var ambitos = L.geoJSON(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        },
            filter: function(feature, layer) {                              
                    if(miSelect != "TODOS")     
                return (feature.properties.tematica == miSelect );
                    else
                return true;
            },  
            style:geojsonMarkerOptions,
            onEachFeature: layer    
                    });     

        markers.clearLayers();
        markers.addLayer(ambitos);
```

I've tried to adapt the code from the example on the link provided earlier () but I can't seem to find the way to call the properties I'm looking for to filter.

When launching DevTools on Chrome to find if there's a problem, the console shows no issue. The code seems to be fine, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `tematicaSelect()` is run on the `change` event. For example, in the tutorial, the use the `onchange` attribute on the `<select>` element:

```html
<select id="ambito" onchange="tematicaSelect()">
```

Do not set `layer` as the `onEachFeature` value in `tematicaSelect()`. As per the tutorial, have a separate function that is designed to be called as the `onEachFeature` callback:

```js
const popup = (feature, layer) => {
  layer.bindPopup('<h1>' + feature.properties.name + '</h1><p>Tematica: ' + feature.properties.tematica + '</p><p>' + feature.properties.bio + '</p>');
};
     
var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: popup,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  }
});

// …

function tematicaSelect() {
  // …

  var ambitos = L.geoJSON(data, {
    // …
    onEachFeature: popup,
  });

  // …
}
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "coder_ID": "CHB",
        "name": "Entorno Escorial",
        "tematica": "Medio Ambiente",
        "bio": "Organización medioambiental de El Escorial y de San Lorenzo de El Escorial",
        "redes": "",
        "website": "",
        "CCAA": "Madrid",
        "MAmbiente": true,
        "Educacion": false,
        "JSocial": false,
        "CClima": false,
        "TransEnerg": false,
        "AgroEco": false,
        "SobAlim": false,
        "EcoFem": false,
        "Invest": "false"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -4.147899127581563,
          40.59572974584587
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const map = L.map('map').setView([40.382439468640214, -3.745878127504685], 6);

const tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

const geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#37b18c",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
};

const markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

const popup = (feature, layer) => {
    layer.bindPopup('<h1>' + feature.properties.name + '</h1><p>Tematica: ' + feature.properties.tematica + '</p><p>' + feature.properties.bio + '</p>');
  };
 
var layer = L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: popup,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  }
});
markers.addLayer(layer);
map.addLayer(markers);

/*L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
        return markers.addLayer (L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions))
    }
}).addTo(map);*/

map.addLayer(markers);

function tematicaSelect() {
  var miSelect = document.getElementById("ambito").value;

  var ambitos = L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      if (miSelect != "TODOS")
        return (feature.properties.tematica == miSelect);
      else
        return true;
    },
    style: geojsonMarkerOptions,
    onEachFeature: popup,
  });

  markers.clearLayers();
  markers.addLayer(ambitos);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.3/MarkerCluster.min.css" integrity="sha512-ENrTWqddXrLJsQS2A86QmvA17PkJ0GVm1bqj5aTgpeMAfDKN2+SIOLpKG8R/6KkimnhTb+VW5qqUHB/r1zaRgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.3/MarkerCluster.Default.min.css" integrity="sha512-fYyZwU1wU0QWB4Yutd/Pvhy5J1oWAwFXun1pt+Bps04WSe4Aq6tyHlT4+MHSJhD8JlLfgLuC4CbCnX5KHSjyCg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.3/leaflet.markercluster.js" integrity="sha512-OFs3W4DIZ5ZkrDhBFtsCP6JXtMEDGmhl0QPlmWYBJay40TT1n3gt2Xuw8Pf/iezgW9CdabjkNChRqozl/YADmg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<select id="ambito" onchange="tematicaSelect()">
  <option>TODOS</option>
  <option>Medio Ambiente</option>
  <option>Foo</option>
</select>
<div id="map" style="height: 90vh"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this but it just removes all markers when selecting a filter option, and can't bring them back even by selecting All. Everything seems to be calling everything correctly. Maybe it's an issue with how my marker properties are structured/named?

Comment: It works in the inline snippet – must be something else when you implement it into your project.

Comment: Been messing a bit with the code from your inline snippet (thanks btw!), and I think it's definitely the properties on my geojson. Been adding more options to filter, and some markers have two or three "tematicas", which I added as an array. Those do not show. But when I set just one property in tematicas, it works well. Is there a way to properly add more than one value in a property so it can be filtered by either of them?

Comment: Yep! Look at adjusting the `filter` method in the object argument passed to `L.geoJSON()`.

Comment: Sorry to abuse of your generosity, but could you give me a tip on what I should be changing in the filter method? I've been trying but can't make it work.

Comment: You should be changing the body of the filter method, such that it returns `true` (or a truthy value) for when an entry matches the filter, and `false` (or a falsey value) otherwise.